# Running curl twice in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send email via php mail function like below but it doesn't seem to work on IE. It works on all other browsers. Below is the code. Is there a reason why???

```
$sent1 = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$sent2 = mail($clientTo, $clientSubject, $clientMessage, $clientHeaders);
if ($sent1 && $sent2){
                    $ch = curl_init("https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "oid=$sf_oid&first_name=$sf_first_name&last_name=$sf_last_name&company=$sf_company&phone=$sf_phone&email=$sf_email&URL=$sf_website&description=$sf_description&lead_source=$sf_leadsource");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "124.254.75.167")
                        //print_r($info);
                    curl_close($ch);

                    $ch = curl_init("http://www.rankreport.com.au/ajax/add_new_lead");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "lead_company_id=1&lead_business=1234&lead_first_name=asdf&lead_website=12314.com&lead_phone=1234&lead_email=test@test.com&lead_package=seo");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);

                    echo '3';
                }
```

Comment: This is server-side, there is no mention in this code of how you are getting parameters in to the code from the browser.  So from what you have written is browser independent.  **How** does it not work, what is going wrong?

Comment: The mail function is working ok in all other browsers. The post is done via ajax to php file which the above code belongs to

Comment: Yes, I understand that - but whatever code makes it work with the others, is not displayed above.  The parameters passed to the script are not mentioned above, so the error is before this.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has nothing to do with browser (PHP is server-side executable), so it isn't browser's problem. You have probably no `$sent1`, `$sent2` defined